# Rolling up values from multiple child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best way to roll up values from a series of child tables into a parent table in SQL Server?

Let's say we have a contracts table.  This table has a series of child tables, such as contract_timesheets, contract_materials, contract_other_expenses - etc.  What is the best way to pull costs / hours / etc out of those child tables and make them easily accessible in the parent table?

**Option 1:**  My first thought would be to simply use a view.  An example might be something like this:

```
SELECT 
   contract_code, 
   caption, 
   description, 
   (
     SELECT SUM(t.hours * l.rate_hourly) 
     FROM timesheets t 
     JOIN labor l ON t.hr_code = l.hr_code AND t.contract_code = c.contract_code
   ) AS labor_cost, 
   ( 
     SELECT ...
   ) AS material_cost,
   ...
FROM contracts c
```

So we'll have a view that might have a dozen or more subqueries like that, many of which will themselves need joins to pull in all of the info we need.

This completely works fine.  Until we have hundreds of thousands of rows.  Then things start to get noticeably slow.  It's still workable, but it the row count gets up too much higher, or the server gets too much other workload, i'm concerned that this isn't workable.

Is there a more efficient way to structure such a view?

**Option 2**: The other obvious solution is to roll those numbers up into physical fields in the parent table.  The big issue with that is just maintaining the numbers when the data might be accessed from a variety of clients.  Maybe it's a report, maybe it's a form, maybe it's some integration service.  So trying to use some premade roll-up SQL file that gets run as an event in the front-end prior to displaying the report / chart / whatever isn't an ideal solution.

To ensure that the roll up numbers stay in synch, we could attach a series of triggers to all of the child tables (and possibly relatives of those, if the numbers in the child tables rely on something else).  Everytime the source numbers get updated, we roll it up into the parent.  This seems like a lot of trouble, but if the triggers are written correctly, i suppose this would work fine.

**Option 3**:  Do everything in the UI.  This is also an option, but with a variety of clients accessing the data, it makes things unpleasant.

**Option 4(?)**:  Since most of these records are actually completed with no need to add more data, i can also imagine some kind of hybrid system.  The base table for the parent contract would have physical columns for the labor costs, material costs, or whatever.  When a contract is marked as Closed (or some other status indicating no more data needs to be entered), those physical columns would be filled in (otherwise they're NULL).  The view which is accessible to the clients could then decide, based upon the status (or just an ISNULL stiuation), whether to directly return the data from the physical columns, or whether it needs to calculate it on the fly.  I'm not sure how the performance would be with this, but it might be worth a look.  This would mean that the roll up numbers only need to be calculated for a few thousand rows at most - everything else would come from the physical fields.

So, what is the right way to do this?  Am i missing other possibilities?

Comment: This might depend on how frequently the base data changes, and the rollups need to be recalculated, vs the frequency that the rollup data needs to be read. Also, how necessary is it to have the rollups "real time", e.g. can they be calculated once a day, e.g. in a daily warehouse data synchronization.

Comment: No, the numbers really need to be real time, or as close to real time as possible.  If not, a user might add some cost info and then be immediately confused when they go to run a report and find that things don't add up right.  The addition of new info is relatively infrequent (as in, the data isn't changing every second), so statically storing the values in the parent table is somewhat more attractive.  But i really like the rather straightforward approach of a view, rather than having to do a bunch of triggers.

Comment: Your comment, however, has led me to a possible alternative.  We could possibly have a status in the contract which would determine if it should use a static value or retrieve it live in the view.  Thus, if you mark a contract as "Closed", it could take the live numbers and stick them into a static column.  Then you have a view which has a CASE statement to either return that static value or use a subquery.  Since the vast majority of records would be historical and therefore Closed, maybe that improves performance?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an [Indexed View](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.120).aspx). This "materializes" the view. Creating a clustered index on the view will allow your queries to go directly to the index rather than all of the underlying tables/queries that make up the view.

*Edit: Modified Indexed View link.*

Answer (score 1):

I think the view is probably the right answer, but the way you have the query written with correlated subqueries in the SELECT list may be what causes the performance degradation when the rows increase.  If you write everything out as joins with GROUP BY, it might allow the query optimizer to simply the plan for the view at execution time and give you better performance.

Have you also looked into [Indexed Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx)?  There are a lot of restrictions to creating indexed views so they may not be a viable option for you, but it's something to consider.  Essentially an indexed view is a sort of denormalization.  It would allow SQL Server to keep the aggregations updated for you automatically as the underlying data in the tables changes.  It may of course degrade performance for inserts, updates and deletes, but it's something to consider if the performance of the aggregations is critical.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, of course.  I will give the GROUP option a shot and try using joins.  I'll report back later when i'm able to compare the performance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the best read performance in this case, indexed views are the way to go.

```
CREATE VIEW labor_costs
WITH SCHEMA_BINDING
AS    
SELECT t.contract_code, t.hr_code,  SUM(t.hours * l.rate_hourly) AS labor_cost
FROM dbo.timesheets t 
GROUP BY t.contract_code, t.hr_code

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UX_LaborCosts
ON LaborCosts(t.contract_code, t.hr_code)
```

Once you have the indexed view you can left join to it. For example:

```
SELECT 
   c.contract_code, 
   c.caption, 
   c.description,
   lb.labor_cost

FROM 
   dbo.contracts c 
   LEFT JOIN dbo.labor_costs lb WITH (NOEXPAND)
     on c.contract_code = lb.contract_code AND c.hr_code = lb.hr_code
```